# MySQL restart takes a time after changing system datetime to future

Tags: mysql, datetime, centos

We have a web module which let users enable/disable NTP settings, Lets NTP synchronize system datetime with specific server, change system timezone and set datetime manually.

We are using MySQL version 5.7 so we let MySQL know about the timezone change by

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Asia/Karachi';
SET time_zone ='Asia/Karachi';
```

During testing we found a problem that after changing system datetime to the future manually and restarting mysqld it gets stuck at

```
[Note] InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 3376912ms. The settings might not be optimal. (flushed=50 and evicted=0, during the time.)
```

MySQL restarts without any issue when date is a back date or date is correct.

Another thing that we noted was that it takes approximately the same time to restart as the difference between current time and the time that we have set. E.g. if we have set system datetime 10 mins in the future it will take 10 mins to restart. Of Course this could be entirely coincidence

Comment: Seems like you're not the only one experiencing that issue - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-5.7/+bug/1600164 . I would try to first stop MySQL, change the time and then start MySQL, so MySQL won't be started 'in the future' or 'in the past'.

Comment: What i am doing is stopping mysqld before i perform any action on time and starting the service again once i am done. This seems to be working for the time being. I am still doing some tests